# azure-pipelines.yml Build UWP mixed C# C++ project

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build my UWP app with azure pipelines.
My UWP project consists of multiple C# projects with one C++ project.
The C# parts build just fine (except the one who references the C++ project) but I don't get the C++ project to build.

It fails with:

```
2018-10-28T15:01:04.7827636Z ##[error]XMPP_API\Classes\Crypto\Aes128GcmCpp.cs(11,26): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AES_GCM' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I know I have to build the C++ project which supplies the `AES_GCM` namespace before the C# project referencing it but how do i accomplish this?

[Link](https://dev.azure.com/uwpx/UWPX/_build/results?buildId=19&view=logs) to an example build which failed

My `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x86|x64|ARM'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  appxPackageDir: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    platform: 'x86'
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload'
```

Comment: Did you try to add another build task only for the c++ project? (before the current build task)

Comment: I'm unable to find any documantation about how to first build the C++ project as a library so it than can be used by the C# build process

Comment: In your computer, how do you build the C++?

Comment: Well, I'm using Visual Studio to build my project since I've never got it to run with msbuild